# VB Register for Com Interop

Tags: vb.net, dll, visual-studio-2012

i am trying to make a COM excel addin in VB from visual studio 2012, but keep getting the following error....

```
Error   1   The assembly 'Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities, Version=10.0.0.0,Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' is not registered for COM Interop. Please register it with regasm.exe /tlb.  ExcelAddIn1
```

I have checked the "register for Com interop" check box in the properties.

I am using visual studio 2012 and excel 2010.

Any help would be appriciated.

Cheers,

Chris

Comment: That assembly should **not** be registered as the message suggests.  Doing so will destroy the registration of Office.  You've got a bit of a mess on your hands, it seems.

Comment: isnt the error message telling me to register it?

Answer (score 4):

1. Install the Office 2010 Primary Interop Redistributable (there is none for later than 2010) from https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508
2. Open an Administrative Command Prompt
3. Run:

```
cd "C:\Program Files\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\VSTO40\v4.0.Framework"
```

and then

```
"\windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\RegAsm.exe" /tlb Microsoft.Office.Tools.Common.v4.0.Utilities.dll
```

4. Rebuild your VS project, it should work now.

Answer (score 0):

Download and install the MS Office Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies.

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3508

Depending on your solution you may need this as well: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=20479

Comment: hi, do i need to download the vtso 2012 assemblys or somthing. I havent really got a clue what to do.

Comment: ChrisM, what does your add-in do? Maybe you would be better programming it using Excel VBA.

Comment: Hi, it's an excel addin in 2 parts. The first is an excel ribbon (which I can get working) the second I wanted a COM file to put some excel functions in. The plan is for it to be distributed to a couple of people. I guess I can just create modules but didn't really want to go down this route. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Open Visual studio command Prompt and register your dll as mentioned in the below format

regasm.exe /tlb